# Keep image fixed inside of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page similar to this one http://www.seattlewebdesign.com/.

As you scroll down, the image stays fixed, however when I try to set the  background as 'background-attachment: fixed' within a div tag, the background image stays fixed to the browser window and continues to remain fixed after scrolling past the div.

Any ideas on how to achieve what I'm trying to do? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: can you illustrate your problem by creating a fiddle on jsfiddle.net?? (if your issue is not yet solved :))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encapsulate it in a `div`
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exhcfnhd/)

```css
html {
  height: 2000px;
}
#test {
  background-image: url("http://www.cssnewbie.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/random-art.gif");
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: In addition, `background-size:cover` will make the image fill the width of the container, `background-position:center center;` will center your background-image, and `background-repeat: no-repeat` will ensure images are not repeated if there's room left in the div. There is also a nifty shorthand syntax for all of this... `background:url('http://www.cssnewbie.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/random-art.gif')no-repeat center center fixed`.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.